# TicTacToe not changing turns

Tags: java

My TicTacToe doesn't change turns. When I press a cell it only marks the 
the cell with mark 'x'. In another words, it only loads the 'x' picture, not the other '0'. The game recognises when someone has won but it doesn't draw the last mark in the winning turn. Thank you in advance.

```
public class Frame extends JFrame{


private Cell cell[][] = new Cell[3][3];
private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3, 0, 0));

Frame(){
    setSize(300, 300);
    setName("TicTacToe");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            panel.add(cell[i][j] = new Cell());
        }
    }
        add(panel);
    }
public boolean CheckWin(char token){
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            if(cell[i][0].getToken() == token &&
                    cell[i][1].getToken() == token
                    && cell[i][2].getToken() == token){
                return true;
            }
            if(cell[0][j].getToken() == token &&
                    cell[1][j].getToken() == token
                    && cell[2][j].getToken() == token){
                return true;
            }   
            }
        }
    if(cell[0][0].getToken() == token &&
            cell[1][1].getToken() == token && 
            cell[2][2].getToken() == token){
    return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean IsFull(){
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            if(cell[i][j].getToken() == ' '){
                return false;
            }
        }
}
    return true;

}


public class Cell extends JPanel{

private char whoseTurn = 'x';
private char token = ' ';


Cell(){
    setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 1));
    addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
}
public char getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(char token) {
    this.token = token;
    MakePictures();

}
public void MakePictures(){
    if(getToken() == 'x'){  
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Pictures/x.png"));
        JLabel label = new JLabel(image);
        pack();
        add(label);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    else if(getToken() == '0'){
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Pictures/0.png"));
        JLabel label = new JLabel(image);
        add(label);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    }


    public class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter{


        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            if(token == ' ' && whoseTurn != ' ')
                setToken(whoseTurn);

            if(CheckWin(token)){
                whoseTurn = ' ';
                System.out.println("Voitit");

            }
                else if(IsFull()){
                    System.out.println("Tasapeli");
                    whoseTurn = ' ';
                }
                else{
                    whoseTurn = (whoseTurn == 'x') ? '0' : 'x';
                    System.out.println(whoseTurn);

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the main class.

```
public class TicTacToe {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame frame = new Frame();
}

}
```

Comment: Where do you switch the `token` from `x` to `0`?

Comment: Personally, i would change how i was utilizing token to be a producer/consumer semaphore... but i don't feel like coding that atm.. just a suggestion

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code ? If so, what have you found ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This declaration is wrong

```
private char whoseTurn = 'x';
```

It must be outside **Cell** class. If not, each cell has whoseTurn set to 'x', and therefore the turn never changing.

It should be:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private char whoseTurn = 'x';
```

Cheers.

Comment: I think that this right here should change turns:                                                           whoseTurn = (whoseTurn == 'x') ? '0' : 'x';
                    System.out.println(whoseTurn);

Comment: It does change. But every cel has its own 'whoseTurn' variable, and they need to share that variable.

Comment: @ArtturiTähtinen did it work? Could you mark it as aproved?

Comment: Maybe, but now it gives error in SetToken() method. this.token = token is error token cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: I've updated the answer. You have to keep private char token = ' '; inside the Cell class. Now should work ok.

Comment: Now it changes the turns like it should and it works like it should be :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!. Remember to mark it as aproved when you can :)